# What does the `[cold.clone]` mean in the symbol list of some specific dynamic library compiled by g++?

Tags: c++, linux, symbols

What does the `[cold.clone]` mean in the symbol list of some specific dynamic library compiled by g++?

There are **two signatures with the same name**, and **one signature is marked with `[cold.clone]`**, the other one is not marked.

```bash
#nm -C libDemoStatus.so | grep RegisterGetHandler
0000000000044370 T v1::ara_api::DoorStatus::skeleton::fields::Count::RegisterGetHandler(std::function<ara::core::Future<unsigned char, ara::core::ErrorCode> ()>)
0000000000029326 t v1::ara_api::DoorStatus::skeleton::fields::Count::RegisterGetHandler(std::function<ara::core::Future<unsigned char, ara::core::ErrorCode> ()>) [clone .cold]
0000000000044630 T v1::ara_api::DoorStatus::skeleton::fields::LocationSt::RegisterGetHandler(std::function<ara::core::Future<apf::someip::DynamicSizeArray<v1::ara_api::DoorStatus::Struct_LocationSt, unsigned int, (apf::EndianType)0>, ara::core::ErrorCode> ()>)
0000000000029346 t v1::ara_api::DoorStatus::skeleton::fields::LocationSt::RegisterGetHandler(std::function<ara::core::Future<apf::someip::DynamicSizeArray<v1::ara_api::DoorStatus::Struct_LocationSt, unsigned int, (apf::EndianType)0>, ara::core::ErrorCode> ()>) [clone .cold]
```

The library was not compiled by myself, so I don't know which version of g++ is used.

Though I have checked many dynamic libraries by `nm -C`, this is the ***first time*** that I have ever seen such a signature.

Comment: Possibly related: [C++ ELF object file symbol table has function listed twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64505490/c-elf-object-file-symbol-table-has-function-listed-twice)

Comment: Also related: [gdb sets breakpoint at cold clone](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=26096). This one mentions that GCC can split functions into hot and cold parts by functional block reordering. These two links should hopefully give enough information to continue searching.

Comment: This is related to optimisation and profiling, see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

Comment: Also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63648838/what-do-the-suffixes-part-and-cold-mean-in-the-result-of-linux-kernels-d

Comment: Some man page for gcc says something about cold: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès There are **two signatures with the same name**, and **one signature is marked with `[cold.clone]`**, the other one is not marked. Why?

Comment: although i wouldn't worry about this too much, i would worry about the design of the code that uses so many levels of namespace

Comment: @John I have no full understanding of it, but looks like there is two compiled versions of the same function. One for internal purpose marked `t` and one for external purpose `T`, probably optimisation is not the same when called from different portions of code.